# Deeplink intent filter to a particular pathPrefix?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I've enabled deep linking on my android app and it's working fine.

However, I want the intent-filter to listen to a particular `pathPrefix` only i.e. `http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/e` and not any other `pathPrefix`.

Is this possible? I'm attaching my intent-filter code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter android:label="My App Name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mydomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mydomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="mydomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/e" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4):

With that piece of manifest, you're telling to your device to launch the Activity that contains that intent filter with all url that have

1. http or https as protocol
2. www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com as host
3. /e as prefix of the path

Since the question is related to pathPrefix, your activity will handle all the urls whose path has a /e at the beginning. For example:

- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/e - MATCH
- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/eXXX - MATCH
- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/e/a - MATCH
- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/eXXX/a - MATCH
- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/e?a=b - MATCH
- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/Xe - DON'T MATCH
- http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/X/e?a=b - DON'T MATCH

Comment: I would suggest this solution too, this was my first intent.

Comment: Is it necessary to specify 2 hosts (one with www, another without)? Isn't just www.mydoman.com enough?

Answer (score 0):

Since the code pasted by you is good for that `pathPrefix`, I'm guessing you want to catch only `http(s)://(www.)mydomain.com/e` and nothing else?
If this is the case, use `path` instead of `pathPrefix` like so.

```
<intent-filter android:label="My App Name">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.domain.com"
                android:path="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mydomain.com"
                android:path="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mydomain.com"
                android:path="/e" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="mydomain.com"
                android:path="/e" />
</intent-filter>
```